# Efficient way to change the color of a drawable and display it

Tags: android, performance, colors, bitmap, memory-efficient

I've got a `Widget` and want to let the user choose the `Color` of some `Buttons`. These `Buttons` are `.png` files saved in the `drawable` folder. I'm using this code to get the images as `Bitmap` and change the `Color` with a `Color Filter`.

```
//Imagine: Color.RED or something....
int color = SettingsDefault.getInstance(context).getMenueColor();

Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), rId);
Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0,
                sourceBitmap.getWidth() - 1, sourceBitmap.getHeight() - 1);

Paint p = new Paint();
ColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
p.setColorFilter(filter);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(resultBitmap, 0, 0, p);
```

I set the "`resultBitmap`" for every `ImageView` on every `Widget update`. My Problem is that I often get errors about the memory limit for `Bitmap` processing or my `Widget` shows the "error-loading-view". Is there any efficient way to recolor an image or replace all white pixels with another `Color`?

I've tried to save the generated images(if the user changed the color) to the internal storage and load them from there but it isn't that much faster.

Thanks in Advance,
J. Doe ;)

Comment: You can try recycling the sourceBitmap after you've done filtering

Comment: see `Drawable#setColorFilter` (or `ImageView#setColorFilter` if you are using it with `ImageView` instead of `Button`)

Comment: @psking this is exactly what im doing right now.

Comment: no, you are using `Paint#setColorFilter`

Comment: Oh thats right.. sorry. But i try to change the color in my Widget-Provider so all i have is a RemoteViews-Object and i have to use its functions..

Comment: ah you are using RemoteViews... so ok forget about what i said, you have to use raw `Bitmap`s, your code is everything you can do